# Directx camera 90degree to the left

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I need change camera position to 90 degree to the left, I use method:

```
m_Transform->SetCameraUPV(D3DXVECTOR3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

How to set 90 degree left ?

Comment: What's the type of `m_Transform`? It does not look like a native DirectX type to me. There are functions for camera transformations, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixlookatlh(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Are you using this code: http://mcbawse177.appspot.com/pastebin.com/a14pR8Zf ? Because like Nico said, this doesn't seem like a DirectX native...